# MapView Inside of ScrollView not disabling the scrolling feature React Native

Tags: react-native

I tried to find solution for this on stackOverflow and tried to implement the solutions given in there(Stopping scroll view of the map view) but it is still not working.
PS: the scrollview is working fine if I remove the maps.

Please see the code here as I am currently on a different branch and midway

[image]

this the view but it doesn't scroll only down

[image]

Comment: Please add your code as text instead of adding a screenshot. It's easier for us to help you that way. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I might be a bit late to the party but, add `pointerEvents="none"`

Like this

```
<MapView
  pointerEvents="none"
  provider={MapView.PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
  style={{}}
  scrollEnabled={false}
/>
```

This works for me. Credits go to `patrick-gleeson` [here](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/1032#issuecomment-564502022)

Comment: Glad I could help :)